# MySQL driver configuration to increase throughput to CloudSQL

Tags: mysql, jdbc, odbc, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying tho increase the throughput on inserts to CloudSQL (MySQL on Google) from an ETL software package. Connections can be made using ODBC or JDBC drivers.

Normal throughput to on premise db's is 5-10k insert rows/sec, but for CloudSQL looks to be < 100. The problem seems to be the latency on the calls, with single inserts being processed.

I've looked at the MYSQL driver documentation and there are options such as `multi_statement` and `auto_commit` which hint at allowing multiple statements per call and increasing throughput.

Are there any guidelines on using either with ODBC or JDBC, especially when connecting from on premise to cloud?

Comment: `multi_statement` and `auto_commit` are not likely to be your performance hitters, but there are other settings which may matter. What's different about the connection to CloudSQL vs your local MySQL instance? What's the app you're running? Have you checked its configuration? What's your current ODBC DSN or JDBC URL? Are you using a driver from the MySQL project, or from a third-party vendor? (My employer sells [a very fast driver](http://uda.openlinksw.com/odbc-mysql-st/), which you can test free for two weeks.)

Comment: The difference is _'the latency on the calls, with single inserts being processed'_ as one has a local network roundtrip (<10ms) and the other a local to cloud roundtrip (>100ms). Batching the statements ... less roundtrips

Comment: Sounds like your unnamed ETL software configuration is more likely to be the thing to change. The ETL should not be inserting 1 row per call!

Comment: @TallTed, indeed it shouldn't. MySQL is the only one of the mainstream db's it doesn't process either multi statement inserts, bulk loads or both. So we know the ETL tool definitely can with suitable db/drivers/loaders, hence asking the question if changing the configuration of the driver. Alternately we could buy **a very fast driver** from a 3rd party, but would need to understand the context of **very fast**

Comment: I wonder whether the ETL is not properly using the ODBC API to check functionality of the target DSN/driver/backend. I already suggested testing with a third-party driver; I'll reiterate that, as we have some tricks for dealing with such applications. (Post to our public [Community Forum](http://community.openlinksw.com) or create a [confidential support case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp) if you need assistance with our driver.)

Answer (score 0):

To increase throughput, you should first identify what is the bottleneck. Here are some possibilities:

- **latency-bound**. This is the case when the majority of time is spent waiting for data to get from the client to the server. This is likely if a) your client has a long round-trip-time to the server and/or b) your client does lots of small writes in series.

  Test the round-trip-time by comparing the result of ping to Cloud SQL and your previous server (For Cloud SQL 1st Gen, use the speed of `SELECT 1;` as the ping is terminated within Google much before reaching the true server.) Find out if your client does lots of small writes by looking at it's code or the MySQL query log.
- **bandwidth-bound**. This is the case if you have a small bandwidth link between your client and the server.

  Test for this by doing a speed test, and seeing if the available speed is below the effective data rate you are hoping for.
- **server io-bound**. This is the case when you have provisioned a Cloud SQL instance with low tier or small disk (in 2nd gen).

  Test for this by looking at the metrics for your Cloud SQL instance in Stackdriver Monitoring.
- **client io-bound**. This is the case when your client can't send data fast enough. This is unlikely if you are using the same source as on your on-premises test.

  Test for this by using `iostat` to see historical disk use or `hdparm -t` to test disk throughput.
- **excessive indexing**. Each additional index makes writes slower. Make sure you are using the same schema on Cloud SQL and on-prem for a fair test.

Comment: Its the latency on the roundtrip which is why we are looking at batching as a way of reducing overall time, batches of 1000 = 1/1000 of the number of calls to the server.